# Problem with Date format using an attribute Calendar with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, date, calendar, format

I've a problem using an attribute Calendar with JPA:

```
@Column(name = "Date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar date;
```

By default it is setted as mm/dd/yyyy and I need it in dd/mm/yyyy,
can anyone help me?

I've seen that is quiete easy with Date instead of Calendar but i can't use it...

Thx
Daniele

Comment: I guess you would need a custom UserType

Answer (score 1):

I think, format doesn't really matter. Neither `Calendar` nor `Date` have any format with them. Its the `toString()` method that formats it in the default format.

Would you care to elaborate,

- what is the expected behaviour?
- what you are getting?

**[Edited based on the comment below]**

Whatever, comes from the browser it comes as a `String`. So, you are having an issue while converting that `String` to the `Date` or `Calendar`. Fix that and all will be good after that.

Happy coding. Cheers.

Comment: Basically the behaviour i that when we put a date thru a JSP, it is inserted in the DB with the wrong date format, for example if we put 1/2/2010 the result is the 2nd of january and for instance if i use 13/09/2010 it becomes the 9th of january of "2011"... in the DB it looks like this: 2012-01-09

Comment: Whatever, comes from the browser is a String. So, you got a issue while converting that String to the Date. Fix that. All will be good after that. Happy coding. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not a JPA issue but SQL configuration.
From what you're describing, your SQL server is configured to default format. You should change it to the format you need.

Take a look on SQL date formats - http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: i don't think that is a MySql issue, even because in the DB itself it is stored in a third format (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: 2nd option - JVM timezone settings

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case, why not you can try SimpleDateFormatter, where you can parse the date and using dateFormatter you can get the desired date format.[For more clarification please try the link.](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-simpledateformat-example.html)

Comment: the problem is that i can't change the model, this way i have to keep on working with Calendar instead of Date

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and let us know:

```
        String formattedDate = "";
        String requiredFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
        Date dt = formatter.parse("13/09/2011");
        DateFormat reqFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(requiredFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);  
        formattedDate = reqFormatter.format(dt);
        System.out.println("Output Date: " + formattedDate);
```

//formatted Date will give you what expects to be there in DB.